# Create indicator list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have 5 lists which have following records:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,7,13,19,21]    
list2 = [1,2,7,13,14,19,21]
list3 = [3,5,6,15]
list4 = [17,18]
list5 = [20]
```

I want to create a single list with the union of all the elements in the lists and indicate in which of the original lists they are present.

```
output_list = [[1,True,True,False,False,False],[2,True,True,False,False,False],[3,False,False,True,False,False],...]
```

Comment: I have no idea how that CSV works. What does ID represent? What is `cat1`?

Comment: @ThomWiggers That I can do. I need a nested list in this format:
[[1,True,True,True,True,True],[]..]

Comment: Its Really Unclear what you trying to say

Comment: What's unclear is the relationship between the two representations, no the representations themselves. I wouldn't say they're even related.

Comment: I *think* the categories correspond to `id in list<x>` for category `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the union between all your lists, you can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set).

Then, you just need to iterate, for all element, through all your lists to test that the element is in the list:

```
table = [[i]+[i in l for l in (list1, list2, list3, list4, list5)]
         for i in set(list1+list2+list3+list4+list5)]
```

Then you can, if you want:

```
print('ID | cat1 | cat2 | cat3 | cat4 | cat5')
for line in table:
    print(' | '.join(line))
```

Or use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.writer) module.

Comment: I don't want to use range function because if you see there is no entry for "8" in all 5 lists still table will show [8,False,False,False,False,False]

Comment: You can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) then. I've edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Exactly what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your expected output.

```
>>>[[i] + [i in j for j in [list1,list2,list3,list4,list5]] \
           for i in range(1, max(list1+list2+list3+list4+list5)+1)]

#output
[[1, True, True, False, False, False],
 [2, True, True, False, False, False],
 [3, True, False, True, False, False],
 [4, True, False, False, False, False],
 [5, False, False, True, False, False],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
>>> for x in set(list1+list2+list3+list4+list5):
...     [x]+map(lambda y:True and False or x in y, [list1,list2,list3,list4,list5])
... 
[1, True, True, False, False, False]
[2, True, True, False, False, False]
[3, True, False, True, False, False]
[4, True, False, False, False, False]
[5, False, False, True, False, False]
[6, False, False, True, False, False]
[7, True, True, False, False, False]
[13, True, True, False, False, False]
[14, False, True, False, False, False]
[15, False, False, True, False, False]
[17, False, False, False, True, False]
[18, False, False, False, True, False]
[19, True, True, False, False, False]
[20, False, False, False, False, True]
[21, True, True, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try following code:

```
def in_list(list,ele):
    if ele in list:
        return 'True'
    return 'False'

csvlist = []
print "ID\tcat1\tcat2\tcat3\tcat4\cat5"
for i in range(max(max(list1),max(list2),max(list3),max(list4),max(list5))+1):
    print str(i)+"\t"+in_list(list1,ele)+"\t"+in_list(list2,ele)+"\t"+in_list(list3,ele)+"\t"+in_list(list4,ele)+"\t"+in_list(list5,ele)+"\n"
    csvlist.append([i,in_list(list1,ele),in_list(list2,ele),in_list(list3,ele),in_list(list4,ele),in_list(list5,ele)])
```

Comment: Your function would be better as `lambda e, l: str(e in l)` (or as a one-line function: `return str(e in l)`). But I believe it's neater to first compute the table and then care about the formatting, rather than mixing both.